# Define two members of a list simultaneously using a function that returns a tuple - Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

This is what I wish I could do:

```
def f: return 1, 2

list = {
    "a","b": f()
}
```

Is there any way to set two elements of a list simultaneously with a single function call?

Comment: Do you really mean "list" or do you really mean "dict" ?

Comment: your function should be `def f(): return 1, 2`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, dictionary.

Comment: Naming a variable `list` is a bad idea, because it prevents you from using the builtin type and constructor with that name. Naming a dictionary `list` is an even worse idea, because it will confuse everyone who reads it.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> dict(zip(('a', 'b'), f()))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show how the function call relates to your answer?

Comment: Where does the call to `f` come in?

Answer (score 5):

Set your attributes *after* creating the `dict`:

```
dct = {}
dct['a'], dct['b'] = f()
```

Multiple assignment works only when assigning, not in a dict literal notation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, from your psuedo-code that you want a dictionary, not a list, but it's worth a note that if [PEP-448](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) comes to fruition (currently slated for 3.4), unpacking into a list will be easy with a syntax familiar to python users - `*` (the unpacking operator):

```
>>> def f(): return 1, 2
>>> a_list = [*f]
>>> a_list
[1, 2]
```